# How to map 1GB (or more) of physical memory under a 32-bit Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, x86, memory-mapping

I have a setup with 2GB of memory and I would like to map 1GB (or more) of physical memory into user space virtual address. It is in theory possible since with 32-bit setup, 3GB of virtual address is available to user land apps.

I updated the kernel command line with the following parameters: `mem=1G memmap=1G$1G`
to force the kernel to see 1GB of RAM and to reserve the last 1GB.

I have my custom driver that will handle the user space `mmap()` call and map the physical address 0x40000000 (1G) to user space address with the function `remap_pfn_range()`.

But the function triggers a kernel BUG() in `remap_pte_range()`. The same call used to work with a 300MB remap instead of 1GB.

I usually used to call `ioremap()` in my driver to map physical address into kernel virtual address. In this case, I can't because of 1G/3G virtual addresses split (1G for kernel, 3G for apps). So I was wondering if it is possible to map physical address into user space virtual address without mapping these physical address in the kernel?

This is a 32-bit x86 kernel, i.e. "i386" architecture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Why does your remap_pfn_range call trigger a kernel BUG()**

The call to  the `BUG_ON` macro in `remap_pfn_range` as per [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L2277)

`2277         BUG_ON(addr >= end);`

`remap_pfn_range`  calls `remap_pud_range` which calls `remap_pmd_range` which calls `remap_pte_range`.

Subsequent calls to `BUG_ON` or `VM_BUG_ON` from `remap_pmd_range` [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L2191)

`2191 VM_BUG_ON(pmd_trans_huge(*pmd));`

and from `remap_pte_range` [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L2171)

`2171    BUG_ON(!pte_none(*pte));`

`BUG_ON` macro is defined [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/bug.h#L53)

as

`#define BUG_ON(condition) do { if (unlikely(condition)) BUG(); } while(0)`

where `BUG` macro is defined above [it](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/bug.h#L46) to print a message and panic.

`unlikely` macro is defined [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/tools/virtio/linux/virtio.h#L114)

as `#  define unlikely(x)   (__builtin_expect(!!(x), 0))`.

So when the target user address to start at `addr` is greater than or equal to `end` which is defined as `end = addr + PAGE_ALIGN(size);`, BUG_ON returns 1 and calls BUG.

Or when `pmd_trans_huge` as defined [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h#L159)

```
153 #ifdef CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE
154 static inline int pmd_trans_splitting(pmd_t pmd)
155 {
156         return pmd_val(pmd) & _PAGE_SPLITTING;
157 }
158 
159 static inline int pmd_trans_huge(pmd_t pmd)
160 {
161         return pmd_val(pmd) & _PAGE_PSE;
162 }
163 
164 static inline int has_transparent_hugepage(void)
165 {
166         return cpu_has_pse;
167 }
```

returns  0, this occurs when CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE isn't configured in the kernel or if 
the `pmd` (Page Metadate) value or `& _PAGE_PSE`

Or when`pte_none` returns 1 if the corresponding entry does not exist and 0 if it exists.

Therefore `!pte_none` returns 0 when the corresponding page table entry does not exist and 1 other wise as the condition passed into `BUG_ON`.

If the page table entry already exists then the call to `BUG` macro occurs.

What happens if you specify a lower a amount of memory than !GB that is greater than 300MB , say 500MB or 800MB ?

So either your starting address is greater than your ending address, or you `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE` isn't configured in the kernel or you are referring to Page Metadata doesn't exist or Page Table entries that already exist.

Clarifying from the comments, your call to `remap_pfn_range` references Page Table Entry pointers   or `*pte`that are already pointing to a page table entry or `pte`.

This means that `set_pte_at(mm, addr, pte, pte_mkspecial(pfn_pte(pfn, prot)));` would fail as the pte pointer already points to a page table entry and hence can't be set to the `pte` that is `pte_mkspecial(pfn_pte(pfn, prot))`.

**Bypassing the 1G /3G  virtual address split**

See the following article [High Memory In The Linux Kernel](http://kerneltrap.org/node/2450)

See the following mailing list [post](http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg30882.html), which discusses some additional information about HIGHMEM with a minimum of 1GB of RAM.

**Information on mapping kernel and non kernel virtual address space to user land**

One way to map kernel virtual addresses and non kernel (returned by  vmalloc()) virtual addresses to userspace is using `remap_pfn_range`. See [Linux Memory Mapping](http://www.scs.ch/~frey/linux/memorymap.html) for additional information.

Another way that replaced the usage of the nopage handler on older kernels is the `vm_insert_page` function

Additional Resources include:

- [Kernel Space - User Space Interfaces](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html)
- [DeviceDriverMmap Linux Memory Management Wiki](http://linux-mm.org/DeviceDriverMmap)
- [The evolution of driver page remapping](http://lwn.net/Articles/162860/)
- [Faulting out populate(), nopfn(), and nopage()](http://lwn.net/Articles/203725/)
- [Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager](http://kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/)
- [Mmap for Linux Drivers](http://psomas.wordpress.com/2009/06/26/mmap-for-linux-drivers/)
- [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition Chapter 15.1. Memory Management in Linux](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1.shtml)
- [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition Chapter 15.2. The mmap Device Operation](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-2.shtml)
- [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition Chapter 15.4. Direct Memory Access](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-4.shtml)
- [Linux Device Drivers 3rd Edition Chapter 9.4. Using I/O Memory](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-4.shtml)

Comment: `__builtin_expect(x, y)` does _always_ return `x`. The `BUG_ON(x)` macro does trigger if `x` is true. So something in your logic chain is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, one too many negations, will updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. The `BUG()` macro is called by `remap_pte_range() BUG_ON(!pte_none(*pte))`.
I have to use an old kernel for my project (2.6.18) and I didn't find the config `CONFIG_TRANSPARENT_HUGEPAGE`.